# Affinity Designer: slice tool doesn't match with the artboard

Tags: artboard, slices, affinity-designer

I'm trying to export different images by using the automatic slice tool in Export Persona mode, but it doesn't match with my artboard and sometimes it adds a pixel I don't need.

Someone could tell me why and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the slice tool, then click the button "Revert to auto sized" in the bar above.

Comment: Welcome! Can you add some screen shots showing the used menu points and result?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, for me it helped to make sure the artboard is positioned on full pixels via the transform studio and not on decimal pixels

Wrong:
[image: wrong: decimal pixels]

Right:
[image: right: full pixels]